# how to modify java delegate activity name in camunda bpmn at run time

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I have one existing camunda bpmn flow, i want to reuse it.
ex.
activity1 -> activity2 -> activity3 -> activity4. like that the flow is going.

i have to reuse this, but instead of activity3 i have to call my activity3.1 version java class.

i have tried using camunda xml model to get the service task and tried to modify by like but didn't worked.

```
ServiceTask processes = modelInstance.getModelElementById(s.getId());
ExtensionElements extensionElements = processes.getExtensionElements();
CamundaInputOutput formData = extensionElements.getElementsQuery().filterByType(CamundaInputOutput.class).singleResult();
System.out.println(formData.getCamundaInputParameters().iterator().next().getTextContent());
formData.getCamundaInputParameters().iterator().next().setTextContent("com.test.activity3.1");
```

Comment: Please provide properly edited code example. The easier it is to read, the faster someone can figure out the solution

Comment: Why do you want do this by hand? Maybe it is easier to use a call activity and call the process ?